# When migrating from a page router to an app router, how should _app.js props be handled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

in next.js 13.4 the app router has been changed to stable. So, I'm trying to migrate my existing page router to the app router.

The _app.jsx is supposed to receive Component, pageProps as props, and I need to get those props in my project now. My question is, when I change this to layout.js, how should I handle the above props?

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

// Question is How can i get Component and pageProps..? at Next 13.4
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return ...
}
```

Comment: `children` will be similar to `Component`, and there will be no `pageProps`, as those props come from functions like `getServerSideProps`, which is not used here anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as page props in a layout component, it's a simple server component that's a father to the page. You can create nested layouts too. If you need props that needs to be passed to all pages, you can fetch the data from the server inside layout and pass it inside a Context provider or whatever you use to manage state.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts